# CSS overflow hidden for larger screens

Tags: css, forms, overflow

I have a form inside a div. The div is 768px tall. That form has 2 inputs that display depending on the development environment. The form has to be inside of the div, but the input field is only needed for development so it's given a margin of over 768px so it will display outside of the div. The screen resolutions used in production is 768px tall so that input field shouldn't display there. I have given the html and body tags the declaration `overflow: hidden` to remove the scroll bars. However, instead of the screen starting from top down, it's displaying from bottom up. So the input field is shown and part of the top of the div is cutoff. I've tried giving the body, the div, the form a 768 height and `overflow: hidden` but when I do that the field gets pushed up into the middle of the div. Basically what I want is the field to sit right underneath the 768px tall div. If the screen is over 768px tall I want the input to display otherwise I don't want it to show up. However I do want the field functionality to continue, so I can't use display none.

Here is how the setup is:

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input></input>
    <input></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't using visibility:hidden an option for you then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning to put the form 768px from the top. Then, instead of setting the body or html height to 768px, set it to 100vh - this means exactly the height of the browser window. So if someone's browser is 768px tall or less, they won't see the form. If it's more than 768, they will. Nobody will see any scroll bars.

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.page {
 height: 768px;
  
    /* just so you can see where the div is */
 background: skyblue;
}

form {
 position: absolute;
 top: 768px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Field 1" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Field 2" />
   </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanx @jack. It definitely looks like this should work. I tried exactly what you're doing but I still get the same results. The production environment is a swipe screen running Chrome so I'm wondering if it has to do with the version of Chrome that it's running. I've never seen this, where it goes from the bottom up and cutting off any over layed from the top. Also I just noticed that if I remove the form's hidden fields it moves up a bit. So there's definitely something weird about the screen.